# gpg.exe (part of Git-Bash) crashes with "fatal error - add_item" (Windows)

Tags: windows, git, git-bash, gnupg

When running the gpg.exe command (part of Git-Bash) I get the following error:

```
gpg (5076) C:\some_path\Git\usr\bin\gpg.exe: *** fatal error - add_item ("\??\C:\some_path\Git", "/", ...) failed, errno 1
Stack trace:

Frame        Function    Args
000FFFFCCE0  001800638AE (00180288FCA, 00180263FD1, 00800000000, 000FFFF8B50)
000FFFFCCE0  0018004973A (00000000000, 000FFFFCCE0, 00180020010, 000FFFFABFE)
000FFFFCCE0  00180049772 (000FFFF9BD0, 00000000001, 00800000000, 525C3A425C3F3F5C)
000FFFFCCE0  001800EB3EF (00000000000, 00040000024, 00000000000, 00000000000)
000FFFFCCE0  0018013DE25 (001800D212A, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
000FFFFCCE0  00180049D95 (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
000FFFFFFF0  00180048846 (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
000FFFFFFF0  001800488F4 (00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000, 00000000000)
```

I am calling it using `subprocess.run` with `shell=True` on a Windows server, but I can also reproduce this crash in powershell.

Comment: I have the same issue sometimes when I try to run any Git Bash executable on behalf of the SYSTEM account. It works if I run it as a regular user. And it starts working for the SYSTEM user too if I reinstall Git Bash. Very annoying!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked was to "tunnel" the entire call through the bash.exe:

```
C:\some_path\Git\usr\bin\gpg.exe arg1 arg2
```

becomes

```
C:\some_path\Git\bin\bash.exe -c "gpg arg1 arg2"
```

and the issue mysteriously disappears!

Comment: Side note: gpg.exe is not actually "part of Git-Bash". I'm not a Windows guy but I suspect this is a side effect of the usual "DLL Hell" problem on Windows. If so, it is the separation between them, along with the fact that they want to use the same DLLs (but don't when you invoke them separately), that is why your solution works: running gpg *from* bash.exe makes it get the right DLLs. If gpg were built into bash they'd share the startup code and both would work from Powershell.

Comment: @torek Thanks for your insightful comment! I just assumed you could run gpg.exe directly like any other Windows executable

Comment: This particular situation, with various programs working when run from some other programs, but not from *other* other programs, seems to be common on WIndows (from what I hear). It can happen on Linux and other systems, but we put versioning information on both sides so that a program knows which version of some shared library it needs and a library knows which version it provides. That helps hook up the right libraries to the right programs. It's not perfect but apparently it's missing from Windows setups.